# matlab histogram bin include is lower boundary

Tags: matlab, histogram, bin, boundary

I know that matlab hist
"Input values that fall on the border between two bins are placed into the lower valued bin; that is, each bin includes its upper boundary."

http://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/histogram.html

Is it possible to change it so that input values that fall in the lower bound will be included in the bin? that is, that each bin will include its **lower boundary**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your documentation refers to the function [`hist()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/hist.html?) which bins according to `lb < x ≤ ub`.  Internally, this function calls [`histc()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/histc.html) which however bins according to `lb ≤ x < ub`. In brief, `hist()` adds `eps(ub)`, i.e. some margin, to the the upper bounds.

You can simply call `histc()` and then plot with [`bar()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/bar.html), follows an example:

```
c = histc(1:0.1:2,[1,2])
bar(c)
```

you can see that the 2 falls in the second bin, since the bins determined by the edges are `[1,2)` and `[2,2)`.